# SQL WHERE versionname like [0-999]

Tags: sql-server, regex, version, where-clause

I need a statement where I can search for version numbers like :

```
1.0.0
1.1.0
1.1.1
1.1.1.1
1.111.1.1
...

SELECT * FROM PROJECTS WHERE vnumber LIKE '[0-999].[0-999].[0-999]' ...
```

Something like this LIKE '[0-9]%.[0-9]%.%[0-9]' is not working for Strings like 1.11.22 Beta 2. I only want Strings with versions like x.x.x.x and no beta or something else.

Comment: There are no quantifiers in SQL Server *wildcards*, you will have to use something like `LIKE '[0-9].[0-9].[0-9]' OR LIKE '[0-9].[0-9].[0-9].[0-9]' OR LIKE '[0-9].[0-9][0-9].[0-9].[0-9]'....`. Or better use a non-regex solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should use patindex.
Something like this

```
SELECT * FROM PROJECTS WHERE PATINDEX('%[0-9][.][0-9][.][0-9].[0-9]%',vnumber) > 0
```

Hope it helps !